# Spring Hibernate - Persist List of Entity as Array of Ids using Attribute Converter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the following classes and entities:

```java
@MappedSuperClass
public class Record {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class User extends Record {
  // id + other attributes...
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class ModelOne extends Record {
  // id + other attributes...
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class ModelTwo extends Record {
  // id + other attributes...
}
```

I'm trying to create a new Favorites entity which holds a List of all the user's favorited `ModelOnes` and `ModelTwos`. To do so I added 2 attributes and created an AttributeConverter class `IntListConverter` which basically takes a List of Integers and persists it as a string (ex: `[1, 2, 3]`).

```java
@Entity
public class Favorite {
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  private User user;

  @Column(name = "model_one_ids")
  @Convert(converter = IntListConverter.class)
  private List<Integer> modelOnes = new ArrayList<>();
  // private List<ModelOne> modelOnes = new ArrayList<>();

  @Column(name = "model_two_ids")
  @Convert(converter = IntListConverter.class)
  private List<Integer> modelTwos = new ArrayList<>();
  // private List<ModelTwo> modelTwos = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Is there a way to map the Ids to the actual Entity, so instead of having a `List<Integer>` I could have a `List<ModelOne>` and `List<ModelTwo>`? I was hoping something in the style of `JoinColumn` would work..

Here's a small example of the `favorites` table using the converter:

```
favorites
 user_id | model_one_ids | model_two_ids
-----------------------------------------
     101 |     [3, 5, 6] |          [14]
     102 |        [3, 4] |          NULL
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible this way, you need to call an in query using id for fetch `List<Entity>` using `List<Integer>`

Comment: @Eklavya Are there any other solutions? The closest thing I could think of is a ManyToMany relationship

Comment: Please, never use ids in place of objects for the associations.  Never!

Answer (score 0):

I think once you annotate `Record` with `@MappedSuperclass` you can do that. Because once you annotate `Record` with `@MappedSuperclass`, it is going to act very similar to java.lang.Object with the exception of `Id` attribute present in every table

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Record {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Favorite {
  @ManyToOne
  private User user;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name="User_Model_One"
         joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="favourite_id"),
         inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="mode_one_id"))
  private List<ModelOne> modelOnes = new ArrayList<>();

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name="User_Model_Two"
         joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="favourite_id"),
         inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="mode_two_id"))
  private List<ModelTwo> modelTwos = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

> https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html

> Designates a class whose mapping information is applied to the entities that inherit from it. A mapped superclass has no separate table defined for it.

**Note:**

Your table will not look in the above format.

Comment: I forgot to add the line, but `Record` already has the `MappedSuperClass` annotation. Also I don't think OneToMany would work since this is a many to many relationship (seeing as multiple users can favorite the same ModelOne and a user can favorite multiple ModelOnes).

Comment: `@ManyToMany` is fine too. It is an extra join table. As long as you are fine with join table, this mapping should work

Comment: My point is with MappedSuperClass, from the perspective of hibernate, you can ignore `Record` class exist  and  imagine it like every subclass itself has  `@Id private Integer id;` defined

Comment: Do you have a git repo?

Comment: The problem I have with `JoinTable` is that it creates a table for each of the relationships. In my example there's only 2 models, but in my code base I have a lot more, which is why I was trying to store them all inside of one `favorites` table. Also unfortunately I don't have a public repo that I can show

Comment: Yeah as I noted in my answer, if you want the same table as in your question, this solution is not suitable. And I don't think you will find a solution without join table for many to many. The question is, would it be possible to create one join_table with `favourite_id`, `mode_one_id` and `model_two_id` as columns so it can act as join table for both relationships if you want to avoid many join tables. I never tried it

Comment: I was thinking of that option, although it would end up looking like a sparse table which I'd prefer to avoid. I was really hoping hibernate had some functionality for this, but if not then I suppose I'll fallback to using `JoinTable` :/

Comment: It is not the hibernate issue, we need to have two foreign keys one pointing to Favourite and one pointing to ModelOne or ModeTwo. Since there is nothing in relational db to achieve it without join table, it is not going to be possible